# Azure Service Bus Function Message.SessionId Different Than MessageSession.SessionId

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm trying to process session-enabled messages in an Azure version 2 function.  Here is the run method

```
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("order", "ordereventhandler", Connection = "xxx", IsSessionsEnabled = true)]Message message, IMessageSession messageSession)
{
    _logger.LogDebug($"Received message: Session: {message.SessionId}, SequenceNumber: {message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber}, Label: {message.Label}, Body: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");
    _logger.LogDebug($"Message.SessionId: {message.SessionId}, MessageSession.SessionId: {messageSession.SessionId}");
}
```

The output shows that the SessionId property of the message doesn't always match the SessionId property of the IMessageSession.

[image]

The reason I am using the MessageSession object is to read any other messages in the queue for the same session. I need to do this so I can process the entire batch of messages at once.  Obviously, this doesn't work right when the first message is for session 12 but the message session is for session 14.

What am I doing wrong? Is there some other way to accomplish the same thing?

**EDIT**

I added the ExecutionContext.InvocationId to the log message.  It shows the results are coming from two different threads.

```
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("order", "ordereventhandler", Connection = "xxx", IsSessionsEnabled = true)]Message message, IMessageSession messageSession, ExecutionContext context)
{
    _logger.LogDebug($"Received message: Session: {message.SessionId}, SequenceNumber: {message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber}, Label: {message.Label}, Body: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");
    _logger.LogDebug($"Message.SessionId: {message.SessionId}, MessageSession.SessionId: {messageSession.SessionId}, Context.InvocationId: {context.InvocationId}");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you log function execution context to see if those two different instances of the function?

Answer (score 0):

From this [comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/16#issuecomment-525086660), I got a solution maybe you could have a try. I set the `MaxConcurrentSessions` and `MessageWaitTimeout` with the follow host.json.

```
"extensions": {
"serviceBus": {
  "SessionHandlerOptions": {
    "AutoComplete": true,
    "MaxConcurrentSessions": 1,
    "MessageWaitTimeout": "00:00:05"
  }
  }
}
```

And then the result will be like the below picture.

[image]

With this setting, the id will be same, however it will process message one by one. Hope this could help you, of you still have problem please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't seem to make any difference.